# JavaScript: Is it possible to add arguments to a class extension?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, constructor, arguments

I am using Toxiclibs Verlet physics engine in JavaScript, and I would like to extend the `VerletParticle2D` class to create a custom object. It seems easy enough to add parameters and methods, but I wonder if my new class can have additional arguments. For example, `VerletParticle2D` takes one argument, which is a position vector.

Could I simply call the the new class with an additional argument, and pass it two vectors, and then define how the new argument is used in the added methods?

Comment: You don't "call a class", you can call a constructor (with `new`). And when you want to extend that so that it accepts more parameters, then you just overwrite it like any other method.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly extend a class like this:

```
class BaseClass {
  constructor(vector1) {
    this.vector1 = vector1;
  }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
  constructor(vector1, vector2) {
    super(vector1);
    this.vector2 = vector2;
  }
}
```

Then create a new instance with `new MyClass(vector1, vector2)`.